# How do I add a dll to a VC++ 2008 project

Tags: c++, dll

I would like to add a dll in my C++ project, but I do not know how I would go about doing this. I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.

Comment: Why would you want to add a dll to the project?

Comment: Because there is a library there and it makes use of functions in the dll

Comment: Is this a *managed* or *unmanaged* C++ project? Are you writing C++/CLI, or native C++ code?

Comment: Its just a regular C++ project, not CLI

Comment: Then fefe's answer is right-on. Working with native DLLs is very different than managed DLLs. You don't need to (nor can you) add them to your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't add an dll to a project. You'll need a corresponding `.lib` file, which would probably provide the entry points of each exported function in the dll, and a corresponding header (`.h`).

To use the functions in the dll, to just `#include` the `.h` in your source, the link to the `.lib` file.

If you don't have the `.lib` file, then you'll have to use `LoadLibrary` to load the dll dynamically and `GetProcAddress` to get the function pointer to be called. (But again, the dll does not need to be put into the project).